# Unable to remove mandatory validation in MVC

Tags: validation, model-view-controller

I am not an expert MVC programmer but have to make a small change in the code. Any help?
I have a field CallerType which had [required] attribute. However, I do not want to be mandatory anymore so I am removing [required] attribute but still get the same input required error.

```
public virtual CallType CallType { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Type of Calls")]
/*Akbar-start*[Required]*Akbar-end*/
public int CallTypeID { get; set; }

<div class="form-group col-3">
  <label asp-for="Intake.CallTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="Intake.CallTypeID"class="form-control">asp-items="Model.CallTypes">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="Intake.CallTypeID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoQC8.png)

I also see javascript like below but not sure how this is getting invoked:

```
$('input').each(function () {
    var req = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
    var hide = $(this).attr('hide-required-indicator');
    var hasIndicator = $(this).hasClass('has-required-indicator');
    if (undefined != req && undefined == hide && !hasIndicator) {
      var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
      var text = label.text();
      if (text.length > 0) {
        label.append('<span style="color:red" class="required-indicator"> *</span>');
        $(this).addClass('has-required-indicator');
      }
    }
  });

  $('select').each(function () {
    var req = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
    var hasIndicator = $(this).hasClass('has-required-indicator');
    if (undefined != req  && !hasIndicator) {
      var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
      var text = label.text();
      if (text.length > 0) {
        label.append('<span style="color:red"> *</span>');
        $(this).addClass('has-required-indicator');
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue.
Here is the trick:

Changed int to int?

```
public int CallTypeID { get; set; }
```

i.e.

```
public int? CallTypeID { get; set; }
```

? indicates that this field is nullable. It was overriding [Required] attribute